# no applicable method for 'unnest_tokens_' applied to an object of class "character" (Error with tidytext)

Tags: r, tidytext

I'm having some issues with converting a dataframe to use with the `tidytext` function `unnest_tokens`

The error is: `error in UseMethod("unnest_tokens_") :  no applicable method for 'unnest_tokens_' applied to an object of class "character"`

From this:

```
notesWords <- text_df %>% 
        unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%
        count(segment, word, sort = TRUE) %>%
        ungroup()
```

I'm not sure what the error is telling me, because when I check the type of my input `text_df`, I get `chr [1:6067]`

However, because I'm looking at the inputs to a document, I need to input characters, so I'm not sure how to solve this error if it is telling characters should not be inputted. Should I convert the characters to something else?

Thanks,

*** UPDATED ***

Here is how `text_df` is created: `data.frame(textData['notes'])`

The contents of `text_df` are:

```
 head(text_df)
                                notes
1                                 foo
2                                 bar
3                                 baz
```

And `str(text_df)`

`'data.frame':  6067 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ notes: chr  "foo" "bar" "baz" ...`

However when I use use the data frame now, the error becomes:

`Input must be a character vector of any length or a list of character vectors, each of which has a length of 1.`

Comment: Looks like you have a `vector`.  Is it a data.frame?  Is the column name "text"?  The example in `?unnest_tokens` works for me

Comment: Yeah, doesn't sound like `text_df` is a data.frame. When asking for help make sure to include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data. This will make it easier to help you. Also include the desired output for the sample input so possible solutions can be tested and verified.

Comment: Updated the question with some sample data

Comment: My quick guess is that you only have a word in each row of `notes`, so `unnesttokens()` is not working.

Comment: For your first attempt, you specified a column called `text` for `unnest_tokens()'. But seeing your sample data in your update, you do not have a column called word or text.

Comment: @jazzurro that was the issue. Thank you for seeing that